# Billion and other large numbers

Tags: american-english, british-english, numbers

Traditionally a **billion** in American English means 10<sup>9</sup> (1,000,000,000, a thousand million) while in British English it means 10<sup>12</sup> (a million million) with **milliard** meaning 10<sup>9</sup>.

Is this still the case or has the world aligned itself to the American way? I'm not a native English speaker and I don't remember hearing or seeing the word *milliard* recently.

In any case what are the common names of the powers of 10?

Comment: I always assumed it was just so the Americans can say they have more billionaires:-)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

> Is this still the case or has the
> world aligned itself to the American
> way?

At least Britain seems to have largely aligned itself that way. [Quoting Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Long_and_short_scales#Notes_on_current_usage), which has an excellent entry on the topic ([Long and short scales](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Long_and_short_scales)):

> [In the UK,] "billion" has meant 10<sup>9</sup> in most
> sectors of official published writing
> for many years now. The UK government,
> the BBC, and most other broadcast or
> published mass media, have used the
> short scale in all contexts since the
> mid-1970s.
>
> Before the
> widespread use of "billion" for 10<sup>9</sup>,
> UK usage generally referred to
> thousand million rather than
> milliard. **The long scale term
> "milliard", for 10<sup>9</sup>, is obsolete in
> British English**, though its
> derivative, "yard", is still used as
> slang in the London money, foreign
> exchange and bond markets.

I wouldn't say that the *world* has done so, however, as the list of [long-scale  countries](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Long_and_short_scales#Long_scale_countries) is rather long. For example, in Finnish the only word we use for 10<sup>9</sup> is *miljardi*, while 10<sup>12</sup> is *biljoona*.

But you could well say that about the *[English-speaking world](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Long_and_short_scales#English_language-speaking_countries_and_regions)* which now almost universally uses "billion" for 10<sup>9</sup>, according to that Wikipedia article.

Comment: When I grow up, I want to be a biljoonaire.

Comment: This is completely the correct answer. Most times when you hear "billion" in the UK you will assume that it is in short scale, but people often ask if it is "as in a thousand million or a million million?" If you are worried about the value, it is best to say which one you mean. Many people (including me) think that the long scale is a better system, so prefer to use that. I never really say "billion" with any meaning, so it doesn't concern me much.

Comment: This is just wrong. Yes, most mean 1'000'000'000 when they say billion  (sadly) but it is still wrong. »bi« means 2. Not 1.5. This prefix is used in many other englisch words too: Bimetal, bipolar, binary, bycicle, ... It always means 2, never 1.5. Therefore billion means 2 and million => million * million or million^2. Not million^1.5

Answer (score 1):

Ha! you guys want confusion... try Japan. They work in units of 10000. Despite their close ties with America... they haven't gone all American.

- 百 = 100
- 千 = 1000
- 万 = 10000
- 億 = 1,0000,0000

And so on...

So, you end up with number like 5000万, which is 5000,0000 (or 50,000,000 how we'd write it)

It would be like saying:

- 1 hundred
- 1 thousand
- 1 ten-thousand
- 10 ten-thousand
- 100 ten-thousand
- 1000 ten-thousand
- 1 billion

Comment: But Japanese people put commas in the same places, i.e. 10,000, 100,000,000, etc.

Comment: Yeah, I know!!! Strange, Isn't it?! It makes it even harder to read (aloud) in Japanese! You see the 10,000,000 and you think (10 million) but you read it: 1 thousand ten-thousand. (ichi-sen-man)

Comment: (1) You should be surprised by the fact that we use a non-English language in Japan in spite of our close ties with USA before being surprised by the fact that we count differently from English.  (2) In Japanese, 10^8 is “1億” or “一億,” not “1奥.”  (3) In Japanese, 10^7 (一千万) is pronounced as _issenman_, not _ichisenman_.

Comment: Moreover, we do not say “1百” in Japanese except in a special context.  The usual Japanese word for 100 is “百.”

Comment: @Tsuyoshi. Yep. I'm aware that "hyaku" is said without stating that it's "one" hyaku. Thanks for the clarification. I can't believe i wrote 奥 instead of 億. Oops! For those that don't know, 奥(oku) means "housewife" whereas 億(oku) means(10^8). Japanese is truly the language of homonyms. You have to be careful!

Comment: I'm not sure about how close those ties are with America. In their locally-produced entertainment, if you have an English speaker, they're more likely to be an American if they're an antagonist and British if they're a protagonist. This isn't just soreness over the last war. Japan itself identifies more closely with Europe than America due to their similar feudal histories and the social classes that descended from that. Note that Japan and Europe are DVD region 2.

Comment: All very interesting, but tangential to the question asked.

Answer (score -4):

The American usage also includes commas in the numerals.

- Thousand= 1,000
- Million= 1,000,000
- Billion= 1,000,000,000
- Trillion= 1,000,000,000,000
- Quadrillion= 1,000,000,000,000,000

---

- Kilobytes is 1,000 bytes
- Megabytes is 1,000,000 bytes or 1,000 kilobytes
- Gigabytes is 1,000,000,000 bytes or 1,000 megabytes

Use the style best understood by your audience.  Also consider what you are enumerating, if it is dollars and miles in the U.S. or pounds and kilometers in the UK.

Comment: A few corrections and suggestions: (1) The use of commas to separate digits in long numbers is commonplace in the English-speaking word. However, in some European countries, periods (.) are used for that, and a comma (,) is used as the decimal point. (2) There is a long-standing dispute over whether a kilobyte is 1000 or 1024 bytes; see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_prefix. (3) The UK measures long distances in miles, not kilometres.

Comment: He was specifying "American usage" not "English-speaking" usage. No need to downvote.

Comment: Saying _the American usage_ makes it seem as it is used only in America (or USA), when it is used also in other countries. There are also two things that are incorrect, as pointed out from Steve Melnikoff.

Comment: My intention was not to say that something was used exclusively in America, just the opposite, I was meaning that I can only speak from where I live, which is America.  I also did not know that miles were still used in the UK, since kilometers are posted in Canada. Also, I am a she.

Comment: So now Canada is the UK? Tsk.