# Is the correct word to use million or billion?

Tags: word-choice

So the financials i see in front of me has the following:

$2,172.5 million. Shouldn't this read as $2,172.5 billion?

Comment: 2,182.5 million is never the same as 2,172.5 billion.  In US English, 2.1725 billion is the same as 2,172.5 million.  In UK English, 2.1725 billion is 2,172,500 million. Where were these financials published?

Comment: Decimal point vs. Comma might be the issue here. 2,1725. million IS 2.172.5 billion; and 2,1725 Billion is 2.175 trillion. If it helps think of it as (two thousand, one hundred and seventy two and half millions) vs (two thousand, one hundred and seventy two and a half BILLIONS). The second is a thousand times greater than the first.

Comment: @jejorda2 We haven't used a million, million = billion since 1974.

Comment: @JoeDark that's because a thousand million equals a billion.

Comment: The value is 2 182 568 978 so clearly 2.1 billion. I just was not sure if it is correct to say 2,182.5 MILLION.

Comment: Related: *[Billion and other large numbers](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/2321)* and *[Is it safe to use the British standard for numbering in a novel with a worldwide audience?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/30321)*

Comment: The text "$2,172.5 million" would be read as "two thousand one hundred seventy-two point five million dollars". If you wanted to use the word "billion" you would change the text to "$2.1725 billion" and read it as "two point one seven two five billion dollars".

Answer (score 1):

From the comments, the full value is: 2 182 568 978 (also written out as: 2,182,568,978).

Using five significant figures, this may be correctly written as:

- 2,182.5 million
- 2.1825 billion

(Note that I rounded *down* because the OP did. It would be more correct to round up to 2,182.6 million since the next digit is a 6. But that's math, no language!)

Note that commas and periods are used differently in different English-speaking countries. You might see 2.182,5 million, etc. in some countries. The comma and period use in the example above is correct for American English.

Regardless, the word *billion* = 10^9, i.e. 1,000,000,000. The word *million* = 10^6, i.e. 1,000,000.

Note that there is some ambiguity around the use of the word *billion*. What I have listed is correct for American English. However, you should check out [this Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Billion) for complete details. Regardless of how one defines a "billion," a "million" is still less than that.

You may "correctly" read it as either "two thousand one-hundred eighty-two point five million" or "two point one eight two five billion." The choice will come down to preference, context, and your interpretation of which will be clearer to the user.

Comment: The question is too unclear to merit an answer.

Answer (score 1):

> $2,172.5 million. Shouldn't this read as $2,172.5 billion?

Assuming you meant $2.1725 billion yes

The reason for writing it in millions is likely to compare with other values in the same article, or amounts which are normally quoted in millions.

Comment: The question is too unclear to merit an answer.